# Custom message show in simple-react-validator library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show my custom error message

```
 this.validator = new SimpleReactValidator({
      messages: {
        email: "Invalid mail Id",
        // OR
        // will override all messages
      },
    });
```

My input tag is

```
 <input type="text" className="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="" name="email" value={email} onChange={this.handelChange}
                      />
 {this.validator.message('email', email, 'required|email')}
```

I want to show my error message "Invalid email Id",

Please any one help me, Thanks

Comment: Is it not working?

Comment: custom message n't working when my field are blank , when I click submit the button, custom message n't showing

Answer (score 1):

After submit, you need to use `this.validator.showMessages()` to show the error messages. Also make sure to re-render the form/component somehow so that the errors are displayed.

I have created a [working example in the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-validator-react-vc9z8?file=/src/App.js) for you.

Also, [See the docs](https://github.com/dockwa/simple-react-validator#3-easy-steps)

Comment: great .. you can please consider to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom message for your input by doing the following

```
const validator = new SimpleReactValidator({
  validators: {
    med_docs: {
      required: true,
      message: 'Please upload a valid medical document.',
      rule: (val, params, validatorP) => !!(val && val.length > 0),
    },
  },
```

Here you can customise the rule and add whatever validation you want
The above rule that I have added is to check if the medical doc array has some value